# How to avoid that an object knows the collection in which it is contained?

Tags: java

Say I have a object class as follows:

```
public class MyObject() {
  // ...
  public double distanceTo(MyObject other) {
    // **edit: check if desired distance is contained in distanceMatrix**
    // **of the collection in which this object is contained**
    // **if not:** some time-consuming calculation
  }
}
```

I also have a custom collection that contains such objects:

```
public class MyObjectCollection() {
  private List<MyObject> objects;
  private double[][] distanceMatrix;
  // ...
  public void add(MyObject obj) {
    this.objects.add(obj);
  }
  public void calcDistanceMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++) {
        this.distanceMatrix[i][j] = objects.get(i).distanceTo(objects.get(j));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the idea is to calculate all the distances between all `MyObject`'s only once and to store them in a matrix. Now when someone calls `distanceTo`on a `MyObject`, it should use the cached value instead of calculating it again.

However, for this to work, each `MyObject` must know the collection in which it is contained - or does it? I want to avoid this due to separation.

(I know that I could store all the distances from a `MyObject` `obj1` to other `MyObject`'s as a field in `obj1`, but I do not want to do this either. For example, this would mean rebuilding the `MyObjectCollection` structure (which I need anyway for other reasons) for each `MyObject`.)

Comment: I recommend you add a parameter to `distanceTo` that is of type `MyObjectCollection`. The method will first check if the value needed is in the cache. If it is, it will return the cached value.

Comment: Ok, but then it may happen that the `MyObjectCollection` passed to `distanceTo` as a parameter is not the same as the `MyObjectCollection` which really contains the respective `MyObject`.

Comment: The method will check this. If `this` is not contained in the collection, it will calculate the distance without using the cache.

Comment: I don't see where `MyObject` even depends on `MyObjectCollection`. Could you elaborate on the example, showing the dependency?

Comment: @VinceEmigh The dependency comes into play when `distanceTo` accesses `distanceMatrix` in order to fetch the cached value.

Comment: @Sweeper I then would have to check whether this and the other object are both contained. Also, the indices may not be the same, so that `distanceMatrix[1][2]` may refer to a different distance as intended. Ok, this can be solved somehow, but I still would prefer another solution if available.

Comment: `distanceTo` doesn't seem to be accessing the `distanceMatrix` in your example. I'm assuming it would be within `// some time consuming calculation`, but you aren't showing where, thus we can't see why it depends on it. [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as most of us don't want to invest the time into figuring those sorts of things out when you could just show us exactly how you currently have it/assume you must have it.

Comment: I have edited the question correspondingly. It is not so easy to show this with code, so I made a verbal comment.

Comment: Youre saying "*Check if the desired distance is in the array. If not, calculate the distance*", but how would you be able to check the if the distance is in the array without calculating the distance before-hand? That's why concrete examples are critical for obtaining good quality/correct answers. This is hard to answer without seeing exactly how you planned on checking the array in the first place. Seems as if this responsibility (caching) should be handled primarily by `MyObjectCollection`. Why don't you check if the desired distance is in the array from within `calcDistanceMatrix`?

Comment: `calcDistanceMatrix` is only called once at the beginning to construct the matrix. And yes, caching should be handled by `MyObjectCollection`, but for this to work, `MyObject` must known its collection, and this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do 2 things in order to separate time consuming calcultion and dependency from collection:

1) On the MyObject separate the logic that gets cached distance and the that does actual calculation into different methods.

2) Move the logic that gets distance between two object into an interface following [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

Here is the modified code showing it:

```
public interface DistanceCalc{

        public double distanceTo(MyObject from, MyObject to);
    }

    public class MyObject{ 

        private DistanceCalc distanceCalc = null;

        public void setDistanceCalc(DistanceCalc distanceCalc) {
            this.distanceCalc = distanceCalc;
        }

        public double distanceTo(MyObject other) {
            return distanceCalc.distanceTo(this, other);
        }

        public double calculateDistance(MyObject to) {
            return 5.0; //this is where time consuming calculation happens
        }
      }

    public class MyObjectCollection implements DistanceCalc{
        private List<MyObject> objects;
        private double[][] distanceMatrix;

        public void add(MyObject obj) {
          this.objects.add(obj);
          obj.setDistanceCalc(this);
        }

        @Override
        public double distanceTo(MyObject from, MyObject to) {
            if (distanceMatrix == null) calcDistanceMatrix();            
            return distanceMatrix[ objects.indexOf(from) ][ objects.indexOf(to) ];
        }

        public void calcDistanceMatrix() {
          for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++) {
              this.distanceMatrix[i][j] = objects.get(i).calculateDistance( objects.get(j) );
            }
          }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the strategy pattern. In your example, `MyObject`would still know its collection but only in its function of a `DistanceCalc`, so I see your point. Maybe I can combine your approach with what @Sweeper has suggested, that is, pass the `DistanceCalc` as an argument to `distanceTo` of `MyObject`.